# can't use span or icon tags on when editing visual composer element

Tags: plugins, tinymce, visual-editor

I'm using visual composer on a theme and i have a call to action component; this CTA has a tinyMCE element and i'm trying to insert icons from font awesome, but when i insert `<span class="icon-"></span>` or`<i class="icon-"></i>` and save the changes, the i or span tag disappears.
Anyone has an idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding a "raw code" block, and styling/adding your icons in that instead of a typical text box.

Comment: I should have posted my answer before, thanks anyways @Kyle1323

The thing is that i wanted to use one of the already made blocks and just add an icon manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is what i did on the **js_composer/assets/js/backend/composer-view.js** file, I changed this block:

```
render: function () {
        var $shortcode_template_el = $( '#vc_shortcode-template-' + this.model.get( 'shortcode' ) );
        if ( $shortcode_template_el.is( 'script' ) ) {
            this.html2element( _.template( $shortcode_template_el.html(),
                this.model.toJSON(),
                vc.templateOptions.default ) );
        }
```

To:

```
render: function () { 
        var $shortcode_template_el = $( '#vc_shortcode-template-' + this.model.get( 'shortcode' ) ); 
        if ( $shortcode_template_el.is( 'script' ) ) { 
            var newHtmlCode = _.template( $shortcode_template_el.html(), this.model.toJSON(), vc.templateOptions.default ); 
            if(!_.isString(newHtmlCode)){ 
                newHtmlCode = $shortcode_template_el.html(); 
            } 
            this.html2element( newHtmlCode ); 
        }
```

Maybe this is fixed on the latest version of visual composer, I was working with an old version, but i recently updated and i haven't tested it yet.

Hope this is useful for someone else.